# Repository with many methods or Entities with foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I have a database with a Customer, Supplier, and Services (this is a gross simplification, I really have about 100 tables)

I am developing a new Entity Framework library for accessing these tables.

> A Customer has many Suppliers
>
> A Supplier has many Services

I am trying to decide which approach to follow -

**A )**
Use mapping to connect the Customer to the Supplier and the Supplier to the Services, then every time I load a customer I get all his suppliers and their services (and other tables loaded)

**B )**
Have no mapping between entities, but provide methods in the relevant repository; e.g. in the supplier repository I'll have `IEnumerable<Supplier> GetSupplierByCustomerID(int customerID)`

**EDIT** *Changed above to IEnumerable based on suggestions.*

Are these the two main approaches when using EF? Which is considered better, from your perspective.

Is there another approach I'm not considering?

Comment: use Linq and stored procedures to get what you need

Comment: Which kind of architecture? I mean, are entities serialized once retrieved from the DB?

Comment: @CR41G14 I want to avoid stored procs, have many databases with identical table layout. So calling from software is more suitable in my domain

Comment: If you have identical table layout then a stored procedure can be copied to each database.

Comment: You could use explicit loading, to get only the entries you need on demand (so A, but without loading everything everytime). btw. A is not really bad, if you use lazy-loading it will be loaded on access.

Comment: @ken2k In some scenarios the will be serialized, but in others they won't.

Comment: @Grumbler85 thanks, reading about that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I feel like putting a repository over EF is always a good idea. You get to abstract  your database logic from your client-side logic (or even business logic). And the specific case that you're mentioning you would be able to do one other nice benefit: You would only get the information that you want when you specifically call for it (like the `GetSupplierByCustomerID` example that you mentioned.

Another approach you might consider is the one that I mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780776/unitofwork-and-entity-framework-contexts/14780847#14780847): Bounded Contexts. The more separation of concerns that you have in your application, the better it will be in the long run for you and your fellow programmers (especially when you want to unit test it all).

Answer (score 2):

I would personnally expose many simple methods.

> Use mapping to connect the Customer to the Supplier and the Supplier
>   to the Services, then every time I load a customer I get all his
>   suppliers and their services (and other tables loaded)

If you only need to get the `Name` of your customer from its `ID`, then the above solution would require you to load useless and heavy object graph unless you use lazy loading, but as you may have some serialization process (3-tier architecture ?), it's a problem for you as you can't use lazy loading in this case.

So you could expose for example:

```
Supplier GetSupplierByID(int supplierID)
IEnumerable<Supplier> GetSuppliersByCustomerID(int customerID)
...
```

I would also recommend not exposing `IQueryable`. If possible, use `IEnumerable` instead. See [this article](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/) for more details about the danger of using `IQueryable` when all implications are not well known.

Comment: Old answer. But I love this approach. Keep the repositories slim, on a per-table basis and bring the data together leveraging multiple (even async) calls in the app tier.

Answer (score 1):

It is just my opinion, I do not know whether it is proper in your case since it depends on your business requirements, but I generally prefer the third option.

1. All repositories return `IEnumerable`s, not `IQueryable`s : this enables all database operations to be finished before running any business logic.
2. All repositories expose methods with optional parameters enabling to declare included navigation properties : this enables to call repository methods with required navigation entities.
3. Create a base generic repository and inherit from it in each of your repositories.
4. Implement unit of work pattern to share context and enable transaction.

sample method signiture from base repository (`T` is the type of entity):

```
 IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationList)
```

Answer (score 1):

When its about to map or not to map, I'd opt for A. There are many advantages to navigation properties (like `Customer.Supplier`) and there are many ways to control lazy/eager loading.

Advantages of navigation properties is that linq queries are much easier to write. Hardly ever you'll have to write a join:

With join:

```
from supp in db.Supliers
join serv in db.Services on supp.SupplierId equals serv.SupplierId
select ...
```

With navigation property

```
from supp in db.Supliers
from serv in supp.Services
select ...
```

Or things like this:

```
from supp in db.Supliers
select new { supp.Name, ServicesCount = supp.Services.Count() }
```

and EF will figure out how to do the joins in SQL.

Having navigation properties doesn't mean that they always get loaded. For lazy loading to happen, two conditions must be met

1. The property must be defined as `virtual` to enable EF to override it in a proxy type with wiring to cary out lazy loading.
2. The context must be lazy-loading enabled. They are by default, but you can turn it off per instance by setting `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false`.

So this also shows two ways to control lazy loading: you can enable/disable it structurally or temporarily.

Apart from that you can control the opposite, eager loading, in two ways:

1. Using the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) statement:

   ```
   db.Suppliers.Include(s => s.Services)
   ```
2. Including navigation properties in projections:

   ```
   from supp in db.Supliers
   from serv in supp.Services
   select new { supp.Name, serv.ServiceName }
   ```

(there are more ways, but these are the most important ones)

This would applies to writing linq queries in your services or repositories. As others have said: don't expose `IQueryable` to the consumers of your service/repository methods.

One last important note: lazy loading is only possible within the scope of a life context. If the context is disposed and a lazy-loading navigation property is addressed, an exception is thrown. At the same time it is recommended to uses context instances with a short life span. So there's the dilemma: expose entity objects or only DTO's or view models or stuff like that. When you expose lazy loading-enabled entity objects a consumer may inadvertently address a navigation property that has not been loaded yet, and the context is gone.